# Is there a way to undelete a table column in big query?

Tags: google-bigquery

If I delete a column in bigquery is recoverable?
If how long for?
Is there a way to undelete a table column in big query?
If I did want to intentionally delete column in a big query table permanently, how do I go about doing this?
Is it possible to delete the column permanently without making a copy of the table (without the undesired column)?

Answer (score 3):

For now, the only way to delete a column is to recreate the table without copying over the column, like:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE yourTable
AS SELECT * EXCEPT(unwanted_column) FROM yourTable
```

The data is recoverable with BigQuery's [time-travel feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for_system_time_as_of). You can query data at any point of time within past 7 days, for instance:

```sql
SELECT * FROM yourTable
FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

The deleted column will fully disappear (non-queryable) after 7 days.