# How to fetch the latest schema change in BigQuery and restore deleted column within 7 days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Right now I fetch columns and data type of BQ tables via the below command:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
   FROM `Dataset`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS 
WHERE table_name="User"
```

But if I drop a column using command : `Alter TABLE User drop column blabla`:
the column `blabla` is not actually deleted within 7 days(TTL) based on official documentation.

**If I use the above command, the column is still there in the schema as well as the table `Dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS`**

It is just that I cannot insert data into such column and view such column in the GCP console. This inconsistency really causes an issue.

If I want to write bash script to monitor schema changes and do some operation based on it.

I need more visibility on the table schema of BigQuery. The least thing I need is:
`Dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS` can store a flag column that indicates `deleted` or TTL:7days

My questions are:

1. How can I fetch the correct schema in spanner which reflects the recently deleted the column?
2. If the column is not actually deleted, is there any way to easily restore it?

Comment: Bigquery and other columnar NoSQL type databases are not supposed to use delete (row or column) operations frequently as they are optimized for data warehousing with OLAP type operations. These databases are supposed to record as much data as possible with little to no deletions/updates of rows/schema.

Comment: @Imad fair point. But we do have the use case, during the developing phase, the schema of relational database is of course being frequently updated, meanwhile we design a pipeline to archive data from relational db to datawarehouse. We don't want those unused/discarded columns to exist in data warehouse. We want the schema synced with the relational ones

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to fetch the recently deleted column you can try searching through Cloud Logging. I'm not sure what tools Spanner supports but if you want to use **Bash** you can use `gcloud` to fetch logs. Though it will be difficult to parse the output and get the information you want.

   Command used below fetched the logs for `google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob` since an `ALTER TABLE` is considered as an `InsertJob` and filter it based from the actual query where it says `drop`. The regex I used is not strict (for the sake of example), I suggest updating the regex to be stricter.

   ```
   gcloud logging read 'protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob" AND protoPayload.metadata.jobChange.job.jobConfig.queryConfig.query=~"Alter table .*drop.*"'
   ```

   Sample snippet from the command above (**Column PADDING** is deleted based from the query):

   [image]

   If you have options other than Bash, I suggest that you create a [BQ sink for your logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2) and you can perform queries there and get these information. You can also use client libraries like Python, NodeJS, etc to either query in the sink or directly query in the GCP Logging.
2. As per this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64712688/14733669), you can use the [time travel feature of BQ](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#for_system_time_as_of) to query the deleted column. The answer also explains behavior of BQ to retain the deleted column within 7 days and a workaround to delete the column instantly. See the actual query used to retrieve the deleted column and the workaround on deleting a column on the previously provided link.

Comment: I am curious why GCP cannot add a flag column into table `Dataset`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_FIELD_PATHS to indicate whether such column deleted and has 7 days TTL. Instead we have to go thru logs. At least give me some operation tables to go thru rather than log history

Comment: @StanPeng It might be better to create a [BQ issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to ask this question and suggest your idea about operation tables instead of parsing the logs.

Comment: This is actually not a good way

Comment: I raised the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/228684146
**Upvote it if you also need it**